# Can Spark SQL be executed against Hive tables without any Map/Reduce (/Yarn) running?

Tags: hive, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

It is my understanding that Spark SQL reads hdfs files directly - no need for M/R here. Specifically none of the Map/Reduce based Hadoop Input/OutputFormat's are employed (except in special cases like HBase)

So then are there any built-in dependencies on a functioning hive server? Or is it only required to have

- a) Spark Standalone
- b) HDFS and
- c) Hive metastore server running

  - i.e Yarn/MRV1 are ***not*** required?

The hadoop related I/O formats for accessing hive files seem to include:

- TextInput/Output Format
- ParquetFileInput/Output Format

Can  Spark SQL/Catalyst read Hive tables stored in those formats - with only the Hive Metastore server running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The [Spark SQL Readme](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.2.1/sql/README.md) says:

> Hive Support (sql/hive) - Includes an extension of SQLContext called HiveContext that allows users to write queries using a subset of HiveQL and access data from a Hive Metastore using Hive SerDes. There are also wrappers that allows users to run queries that include Hive UDFs, UDAFs, and UDTFs.

This is implemented by depending on Hive libraries for reading the data. But the processing happens inside Spark. So no need for MapReduce or YARN.

Comment: It's actually very easy to try. Did you try it and encounter some problems?

Comment: The intent is to understand what the limitations are if we were to go that route.  So just trying may not capture those cases.  For sure if we tried to access HBASE that way it would fail - since hbase TableINputFormat goes through map/Reduce. But that is just an example - there may be other situations.